# USB/Bridge using MAX3421

Tags: raspbian, usb, kernel, spi

Please, could someone help me, I am trying to use the module (max3421-hcb) with the raspberry pi 3, but I really don't know how to load this module, with the parameters, like wich GPIO will act as INT or the speed (clock).

I have compiled the kernel 4.14 with the config CONFIG_USB_MAX3421_HCD=m, so I have the module max3421-hcb.ko, but it seen not be working.

I am using the USB/SPI Shield from sparkfun but even when I load the module using modprobe max3421-hcb I don't get any message in the syslog or dmesg that indicates that the kernel is recognizing the max3421.

I have followed this example: [mcp2515-can0-overlay.dts](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/mcp2515-can0-overlay.dts) and goted this file:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2836", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";
/* disable spi-dev for spi0.0 */
fragment@0 {
    target = <&spi0>;
    __overlay__ {
        status = "okay";
    };
};

fragment@1 {
target = <&spidev0>;
__overlay__ {
    status = "disabled";
};
};

/* the interrupt pin of the usb-controller */
fragment@2 {
    target = <&gpio>;
    __overlay__ {
        usb0_pins: usb0_pins {
            brcm,pins = <25>;
            brcm,function = <0>; /* input */
        };
    };
};

/* the clock/oscillator of the usb-controller */
fragment@3 {
    target-path = "/clocks";
    __overlay__ {
        /* external oscillator of max3421 on SPI0.0 */
        usb0_osc: usb0_osc {
            compatible = "fixed-clock";
            #clock-cells = <0>;
            clock-frequency  = <25000000>;
        };
    };
};

/* the spi config of the usb-controller itself binding everything together */
fragment@4 {
    target = <&spi0>;
    __overlay__ {
        /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        usb@0 {
            compatible = "maxim,max3421";
            reg = <0>;
            maxim,vbus-en-pin = <3 1>;
            spi-max-frequency = <25000000>;
            interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
            interrupts = <25 8>;
            clocks = <&usb0_osc>;
        };
    };
};
__overrides__ {
    oscillator = <&usb0_osc>,"clock-frequency:0";
    spimaxfrequency = <&usb0>,"spi-max-frequency:0";
    interrupt = <&usb0_pins>,"brcm,pins:0",<&usb0>,"interrupts:0";
    };
};
```

I'm using this setup to try make MAX3421E work:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 9
- Kernel Linux raspberrypi 4.15.17-v7+

  - With MAX3421-HCB compile as module
  - spi0-max3421e.dtbo inside /boot/overlay
  - Line dtoverlay=spi0-max3421e in /boot/config.txt

Printout of command raspi-gpio get 25,8,10,9,11

```
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_CE0_N
GPIO 9: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MISO
GPIO 10: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MOSI
GPIO 11: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_SCLK
GPIO 25: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT;
```

Sparkfun SPI USB Arduino Shield

```
D7 (RESET) - connected to 5Vdc
D8 (GPX) - not connected
D9 (INT) - connected to BCM25 (Pin 22)
D10 (SS) - connected to BCM8 (Pin 24)
D11 (MOSI) - connected to BCM10 (Pin 19)
D12 (MISO) - connected to BCM9 (Pin 21)
D13 (SCK) - connected to BCM11 (Pin 23)
VIN - connected to Raspberry Pi Pin 2
```

On boot the module max3421-hcb do not is load automatically, I believe that it should be, because of dtoverlay=spi0-max3421e

Even with sudo modeprobe max3421-hcb:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsmod
Module Size Used by
max3421_hcd 20480 0
spidev 16384 0
```

I get 0 messages inside syslog or dmesg

When I was using the version 4.14 of the kernel I alter the file max3421-hcb.c to be like the one in 4.15 kernel! Now I'm using a full 4.15.y kernel, but no result either.

Best Regards

Comment: Raspberry Pi is using overlays. Have you had a look at `/boot/overlays/README`?

Comment: I just updated my question, using the overlay file, can you have any sugestions?

Comment: No sorry, I don´t have any idea. I'm not so familiar with overlays and haven't compiled a kernel for a Raspberry Pi so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and the problem was the driver in the 4.14 kernel that doesn't support device tree.

I've updated the max3421-hcd.c file with the most recent version (from 4.16) and used a custom DTS file , a bit different from yours, but essentially the same:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
    /* Disable spidev for spi0.1 - release resource */
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            spidev@1{
                status = "disabled";
            };
        };
    };

    /* Set pins used (IRQ) */
    fragment@1 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            max3421_pins: max3421_pins {
                brcm,pins = <6>;        //GPIO6
                brcm,function = <0>;    //Input
            };
        };
    };

    /* Create the MAX3421 node */
    fragment@2 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            //avoid dtc warning 
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            max3421: max3421@1 {
                reg = <1>;  //CS 1
                spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
                compatible = "maxim,max3421";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&max3421_pins>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                interrupts = <6 0x2>;       //GPIO6, high-to-low
                maxim,vbus-en-pin = <1 1>;  //MAX GPOUT1, active high
            };
        };
    };

    __overrides__ {
        spimaxfrequency = <&max3421>,"spi-max-frequency:0";
        interrupt = <&max3421_pins>,"brcm,pins:0",<&max3421>,"interrupts:0";
        vbus-en-pin = <&max3421>,"maxim,vbus-en-pin:0";
        vbus-en-level = <&max3421>,"maxim,vbus-en-pin:4";
    };
};
```

I noticed that, when nothing appears in dmesg, it is because the driver hasn't been matched when probing. Since I can't comment yet, I can't ask you for more details to help with this issue. But try taking a look at the running device tree (`dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree`) to verify if the overlay is active. You should see something like this:

```
spi@7e204000 {
            compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-spi";
            clocks = <0x8 0x14>;
            status = "okay";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0x2 0x16>;
            cs-gpios = <0xe 0x8 0x1 0xe 0x7 0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            dma-names = "tx", "rx";
            phandle = <0x1c>;
            reg = <0x7e204000 0x1000>;
            pinctrl-0 = <0xc 0xd>;
            dmas = <0x9 0x6 0x9 0x7>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";

            spidev@1 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                status = "disabled";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x0>;
                phandle = <0x59>;
                reg = <0x1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <0x7735940>;
            };

            max3421@1 {
                maxim,vbus-en-pin = <0x1 0x1>;
                compatible = "maxim,max3421";
                interrupt-parent = <0xe>;
                interrupts = <0x6 0x2>;
                phandle = <0x73>;
                reg = <0x1>;
                pinctrl-0 = <0x72>;
                spi-max-frequency = <0xf4240>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
            };

            spidev@0 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x0>;
                phandle = <0x58>;
                reg = <0x0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <0x7735940>;
            };
        };
```

Just note that I'm using SPI0.1, and GPIO6 as interrupt, on a RaspberryPi 2

Comment: I am using the same dts file, but using kernel 4.14, 4.15 and 4.16 in all of then I am getting this messages: [  350.556370] max3421_handle_irqs: BUSEVENT Bus Resume Done
[  489.629296] INFO: task kworker/0:0:1461 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  489.629306]       Not tainted 4.15.18-v7+ #1
[  489.629312] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder in case someone else stumble on this thread in the future, I got the max3421 working for an RPi 0 W 1.1 on kernel 5.10.63+ while building the kernel module 'out of tree' & only DL-ing the necessary headers.

Since a .dts overlay is the only thing missing in the RPi firmware repo on github ( as of today at least ), I'll be pushing my tweak as soon as I get enough infos on the best way to make the .dts support multiple spi&ce configs, as well as possibly multiple GPOUTx ( & GPINx ? ).

The current 'POC' writeups are hosted here, enjoy :)

- non-working steps ( interesting read, maybe worth soemthing ? .. ):
  https://github.com/stephaneAG/RPi/blob/master/max3421_spiUsbHost.md
- working steps:
  https://github.com/stephaneAG/RPi/blob/master/max3421_spiUsbHost_working.md